# Generate a secure numeric hash from string in Node

Tags: node.js, hash, cryptography

I would like to generate a secure **digit** code of fixed length from a string in Node. The interface would look something like:

```
hashStringToNumericCode("arandomhash", 6) => "041558"
```

The idea would be to use the generated code as a type of password. So it doesn't need to be unique, but it should be randomly distributed. Assume that the input string is the output of a SHA-1 hash function. In other words, assume that the input string is randomly distributed.

How could that be implemented?

Comment: Note that there are only a million 6-digit codes (<20 bits of entropy), so if attackers can guess at even pretty slow speeds, this can be brute forced quickly. It's very difficult to make this a secure hash.

Comment: You should take a look at HOTP/TOTP. You can use your "hash" or "password" as the key, although I'd recommend putting it through PBKDF2

Comment: @RobNapier Ack. We'd be rate limiting to 1 guess per second and expiring code after 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

```
function hashStringToNumericCode (word, length) {
  let num = 1
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    const bufferValue = Buffer.from(word[i])
    const intValue = parseInt(bufferValue.toString('hex'), 16)
    num *= intValue
  }
  let modulusNumber = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    modulusNumber += '9'
  }
  modulusNumber = parseInt(modulusNumber)
  num %= modulusNumber
  console.log(num)
}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful to explain what this code is trying to do so that future searchers can determine if it is likely to meet their needs.